# How can I to use Task to deal with more than 100 files by parallel way

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task

I want to deal with files by a parallel way, before I tried to use for-loop to create task for dealing with each file, it's not a good ideal. So I hope to control the number of tasks which to be created ,and each one of tasks completed, then create another new task, until all the files to be updated.  How can I do that?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it.  Async processing is great for many things, but there's limits, and trying to process 100 files at once is well beyond the normal limits.  Also note that the actual thread management (which you'd have to handle), is extremely low level and largely abstracted away by the framework.  I suggest a different approach than what you're asking (such approach I can't advise on without more info).

Comment: Can you tell me the different approach?

Comment: Is the work to process each file expensive in terms of CPU time?

Comment: The file is .c file. I want to develop a tool which can compile to each file(*.c,*.h) by invoke compiler, such as CodeWarrior,  instead of using makefile. So that I can improve the speed of compiling the project.

Answer (score 4):

Don't process files in parallel, because the hard disk wastes a lot of time on switching between files. Unless you have physically different hard disks, for example you have 5 files on your SSD C: drive and another 5 files on another non-SSD disk, you can process two files concurrently, because each hard drive has its own probe.